# Disabling ssh autologout in Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, kubernetes

We have ~20 VMs running Ubuntu 18.04.2 in our freshly deployed K8s cluster here and each of them keeps closing my idle ssh sessions in mere minutes. Hence 2 questions to stop this disaster: (1) What exactly piece of config do I add into their cloud_init.cfg file before redeploying them all from scratch, and (2) can I perhaps make some (permanent) changes in the already deployed ones to avoid redeploying them now? Security is not a concern. Many thanks in anticipation.

Comment: You problem is quite likely is with something that you are not describing - your infrastructure. I have VMs running kubernetes on Ubuntu 18 and my ssh session do not keep closing. I did not have to do any specific modifications for that.

Comment: When building those VMs I had to use the base image I was given, perhaps it has some security stuff hardened. Still it'd be great to know how to deal with existing VMs as using a different base image may not be an option. Also I have a VM with a different Linux right next and my ssh session into it lasts for months...